# ViewBag.Title vs. Page.Title in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why sometimes `@ViewBag.Title` contains the right page title while `@Page.Title` is null? We are debugging our View/Layout code and we noticed this difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct is using `ViewBag.Title`, because it is on the context of your `ViewBag` property of your `View` while `Page.Title` is something that comes from asp.net webforms. That is the reason why `Page.Title` is null, there is no context for it.

Comment: This is not correct. `Page.Title` in this context comes from the Web Pages framework, not Web Forms. You can set its value in the _ViewStart file.

Answer (score 9):

When your are using asp.Net MVC you have a few tools you can use to get data to your page.

1. The model you send to the view.
2. The ViewBag.
3. TempData.
4. Cookies.
5. Session.

Each one of theese has their own use cases
The example we will be using is a basic 
List and update View 
For a collection of companies

**The Model**

The model Should be used whenever you have a **defined** dataset being sent to a view and should contain the **primary** data for the page and usally a model is **specific to a page or controller**.

**The ViewBag**

The ViewBag should be used whenever you need to send **general** data to a page that is **not defined on the model** or data that is used **across your view tree**.

**Temp Data**

Temp Data is as the name states storage for temporary data this should be used **in cases where you are unsure if the data will reach its destination** or when you want to **pass data between actions without adding parameters**.

**Cookies**

Cookies are like **Global variables** the host data across your entire application.

**Session**

Sessions like cookies are global variables but differ in their lifetime sessions can be used for things like **Storing form data between requests** dont use session to do this rather use something like http://garlicjs.org/

Lets look at the example 
We have the following ViewModel

```
public class Company 
{
  public int? id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The layout page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    //This looks for the Title property on the ViewBag and inserts it in the title tags
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   @Html.Action("Header", "PageElements")
   @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

The Header Action on the PageElements Contoller looks like this

```
public PartialViewResult Header()
{
  ViewBag.CurrentLink = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CurrentLink"];

  return PartialView();
}
```

The Header Partial View looks like this

```
<header>
   <ul> 
      <li class="@(ViewBag.CurrentLink == "Home" ? "Current" : "")"> 
          @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
      </li>
      <li  class="@(ViewBag.CurrentLink == "Companies" ? "Current" : "")"> 
          @Html.ActionLink("Companies", "Index", "Companies")
      </li>
   </ul>
</header>
```

The controller action for update looks like this

```
public ViewResult Update(int id)
{  

  //Gets a company from the database
  var model = db.GetCompany(id);

  //Sets The Title property on the ViewBag to Update : CompanyName
  ViewBag.Title = String.Format("Update : {0}", model.Name);  

  //Sends the company to the view
  return View(model);
}
```

The update view looks like this

```
@model Application.Models.Company
@{
   Layout = "_layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.id)

   @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Name)

   @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description)
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Description)
   <button>Submit</button>
}
```

The Post Action for Update looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Company model)
{ 
  //Attempts to update the model 
  if (model.Update())
  {
     //Set the message to update succeeded
     TempData["Message"] = String.Format("{0} Successfully updated");
  }
  else   
  {
     //Set the message to update failed
     TempData["Message"] = String.Format("{0} filed to update");
  } 

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The Controller action for companies looks like this

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
  //Index is the entrypoint for companies so we set the currentlink to companies while we are in companies
  HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CurrentLink"] = "Companies";      

  //Gets the success or failure message from the temp data
  ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"]; 

  //Sets The Title property on the ViewBag to List of companies
  ViewBag.Title = "List of companies";

  var model = db.GetAllCompanies();

  return View(model);
}
```

The view for the list looks like this

```
@model IEnumrable<Application.Models.Company>
@{
   Layout = "_layout.cshtml";
}
<span>@ViewBag.Message</span>
<ul>
@foreach (var company in Model) 
{
  <li>@company.Name : @company.Description @Html.AnchorLink("Edit", "Update", new { company.id}) </li>
}
</ul>
```

Lets discuss how the flow of this application works

1. The Index Action gets triggered on companies.
2. We set the current link to companies in a **Cookie**
3. Then we set the Title in the **ViewBag**
4. We check the TempData for messages and put them into the **ViewBag**
5. Then we put the collection of companies into a **Model** and send it to the page.
6. Now razor kicks in and starts renders the page first
7. Then the layout renders and gets the Title value from the **ViewBag**
8. Then the header partial view renders and gets the currentlink value from a **Cookie**
9. We click the update button for a company
10. The update action runs
11. Gets the company from a database and sends it to the view in a **Model**
12. We change the title to update in the **ViewBag**
13. The page renders first and puts the company data on the form, from the **Model**
14. Then the layout renders and Gets the title value from the **ViewBag**
15. Then the header renders and gets the currentlink from a **cookie** (the value is still companies we did not have to change it)
16. Then we submit the form and add a message to the **TempData**
17. now we are back at the company list and we can get the success or failure message from the **TempData**

We used the **Model** to send **Specific** data to the view.
We used the **ViewBag** to send **General** data to the view and the layout.
We used **TempData** to pass data between actions **without using parameters**.
We used **Cookies** to Store **data that wouldn't change for a while**.