# asp.net Mvc _Layout

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

[image: a]

as you see in the pic i have Home / overview

this is the code :

```
  <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index" , "Home")">Home page</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Overview</li>
            </ol>
```

this is in Layout in asp.net `MVC`, so i can to change the name of overview to the name of the other page which i selected  dynamically?

for example when I go to customer page I want to come like this

Home/ customers

I want this come dynamically so I don't write the same code in all pages it is possible to do that ?

Comment: You can use @ViewBag.PageTitle on in _layout. Please provide your _Layout breadcrum code So its better to give you proper answer.

Comment: Or if you don't want to write code by yourself, you can use NuGet package MvcBreadCrumbs.
Link from github https://github.com/thelarz/MvcBreadCrumbs

Comment: thank you i add the code ,, i forget to write the code before

Comment: Added detailed answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll do this as follows:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">@ViewBag.Title</li>
```

More on SO: [ViewBag.Title vs. Page.Title in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206280/viewbag-title-vs-page-title-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

To do the job you need to have a site map.
First of all, you need to install an MVC sitemap component. This component is very popular: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider

You can also check this tutorial to learn how you can use it: https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2014/10/03/asp-net-mvc-5-menu-using-site-map-provider-bootstrap-3-navbar/
But in summary: you should use a helper as below:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap()
```

which read a site map and based on the sitemap shows the breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

So you can do like this on layout:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">@ViewBag.PageTitle</li>
```

From  over view content page (The page using _Layout)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.PageTitle = "Overview"
}
```

From another page Customers (cshtml) (The page using _Layout)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.PageTitle = "Customers"
}
```

So when you hit any page whatever assign to -> ViewBag.PageTitle will show on main layout (On your screen).

Comment: Mark as answer if your problem is fixed. Thanks.